# docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec format error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-machine, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed docker.io and the docker status is running and active. I acreaa group and added docker. I also added my user to docker group. When I run `docker run hello-world` , I am ending up with the error **docker: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec format error".** I restarted my machine and docker, still no go.

Docker version output:

Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Thu, 16 Jun 2016 21:17:51 +1200
 OS/Arch:      linux/386

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Thu, 16 Jun 2016 21:17:51 +1200
 OS/Arch:      linux/386

Comment: Can you post the output of `docker version`?

Comment: @EltonStoneman I have update the docker version.

Comment: maybe old ubuntu/linux version? got same error with ubuntu 14.04 newer version has worked 14.04.11(?)

Comment: @opHASnoNAME Ubuntu version is **16.04**